# OpenGL, Visual Code on Ubuntu Studio 22.04

Tags: 22.04, opengl, ubuntu-studio, ardour

Will installing Visual Code and OpenGL on Ubuntu Studio 22.04 have any negative effects on either audio in Ardour or video processing?